# C# SQLConnection accepting self-signed Server certificate even with TrustServerCertificate=false

Tags: c#, sql-server

we have C# client that connects to SQL Server 2014 database. Currently, connection is not encrypted, but we'd like to change that. For testing purposes we have no certificate issued by trusted root CA, so the one that is used for encryption is created and self-signed by db instance.

If we force encryption on client side (and server does not force encryption), certificate has to be either issued by trusted root CA or we can use TrustServerCertificate=true in connection string. If application should not trust self-signed certificate, connection is not estabilished - this is as expected.

What is a bit strange is that when we leave default values for connection string for client application (Encrypt=false;TrustServerCertificate=false) and force connection encryption on db instance (through Configuration Manager), our application estabilishes connection and runs just fine.

Question: why does SqlConnection not throw exception on self-signed server certificate when server forces such encryption?

Comment: It may make some form of "purist" sense to insist on validating the certificate, but bear in mind, the client opened up contact in the first place and said it was fine with doing everything in the clear. The server then declared that it wanted more privacy, and suddenly the client turns around and says "your privacy settings aren't good enough for me" seems a tad odd.

Comment: SQL Server has Windows Authorization and SQL Database authorization. You probably have both setup.  Usually the recommendation is to use Windows Authorization which will use the Windows Login.  Then setup a Group Account in Windows for all users.